# Does a mirror reflecting a mirror's image go darker than the original mirror image or remain constant? Is there a constant ratio of decreasing light?

Tags: visible-light

I noticed before that mirrors don't adequately reflect the light level of the room. My question was if there were two same caliber mirrors, one reflecting image of the first one, would it go darker again or would the light stay the same as the level as the original mirror? I am guessing the former, but I was curious about what the ratio would be of the original image. Would it be predictably just the same light percent off per mirror added or some other type of variation?

Answer (score 3):

> would it go darker again

Yes. You're losing light with every bounce. A typical household mirror is somewhere around 80 to 85% efficient, so with every reflection you're going to lose 15 to 20% of the image. From the images I've see the losses seem less, perhaps 10%. For instance, you can see that it is getting darker the "further in" you go in this image, but it's not a *lot* darker.

[image]

Comment: I was curious if it might be less as my thoughts were that the light type which isn't reflected well would already be accounted for in the first reflection.